# Is it possible to create a permanent survey?

Tags: survey, surveymonkey

every time we deliver a project (approx. 10 times /week) to a client we would like to conduct a survey.

This survey is always the same - so instead of creating 10 new surveys pr. week - we would like to create 1 permanent survey - and invite(using the API) the client to respond to this survey every time we finish a project.

Is this possible ?

Comment: Guess you are abusing their hospitality. Why not host a similar web site yourself

Comment: What do you mean by "abusing"?

Comment: I have no intent of bypassing any limitations - im only explaining my need.

Comment: But if you have that requirement so much for your business would it be a good idea to have your own system?

Comment: that is a good question - but in order to answer this I need to investigate the possibilities of existing platform - hence my original question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the send flow API to attach a new email collector and send a link to the survey out.

https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/send_flow